# Data Frame modification based on values in two columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1               | col2
-----------------------------------
green John Simon   | John Simon
Ann Still red      | ANN StiLL
black Terry Johnson| Terry Johnson
```

And I need to create 2 new columns (col3 and col4) based on conditions below.

If value from col2 is in col1 (be aware that size of letter could be different in col1 and col2!!!) then create two new columns for this value:

- in first new col (col3) add value from col2 which is in col1
- in second new col (col4) add value which is in col1 together with value from col2

So, based on Data Frame and conditions I need to create columns like below:

```
col1                | col2         | col3         | col4
-----------------------------------------------------------
green John Simon    |John Simon    |John Simon    |green 
Ann Still red       |Ann Still     |Ann Still     |red
black Terry Johnson |Terry Johnson |Terry Johnson |black
```

How to do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: eh your input doesn't match, col2 is `ANN StiLL` is gone?

Comment: Should `col3` always contains all the words from `col2` ?   What if only one word in common between `col1` and `col2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use col2 to construct an ignore-case regex, which removes that portion from the col1. Then use [`Series.str.title`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) on col2 to construct col3 and strip the regex result for col4.

Because `Series.str.replace` does not take a changing regular expression (trying it, contra Obi-Wan's warnings, throws `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`), I'll use apply.

```
df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.title()
df['col4'] = df.apply(
    lambda r: re.sub(r['col2'], '', r['col1'], flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip(), 
    axis=1)
```

Note that `re.sub` takes variables in the order `regex`, `replacement`, `string_to_replace_in`. I have no idea why they decided on this unintuitive parameter order.

Thus (I know the column order is wrong, just generate the columns in the order of the code above rather than the code below) ---

```
>>> df['col4'] = df.apply(lambda r: re.sub(r['col2'], '', r['col1'], flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip(), axis=1)
>>> df
            col2                 col1   col4
0     John Simon  green John Simon     green
1      ANN StiLL  Ann Still red          red
2  Terry Johnson  black Terry Johnson  black

>>> df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.title()
>>> df
            col2                 col1   col4           col3
0     John Simon  green John Simon     green     John Simon
1      ANN StiLL  Ann Still red          red      Ann Still
2  Terry Johnson  black Terry Johnson  black  Terry Johnson
```

Comment: Does your solution take into account that values in col1 and in col2 could have dufferent size of letter? as in Ann Still red (col1) and ANN StiLL in col2 ?

Comment: I think if you remove the `re.IGNORECASE` then you will match the OP's requirements, that said it's confusing as the ideal output goes directly against the requirement.

Comment: Ok, perfect, gave best answer, thank you very much !